# Integrating VisaCheckout in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway

Hello i'm newbie with Magento 2, I'm integrating **visa-checkout** button in **checkout** of magento

Image is printed but i getting an error about **Refused to load the image** because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

> "img-src 'self' data: *.visa.com *.doubleclick.net cdn.betrad.com
>   l.betrad.com www.google-analytics.com www.google.com maps.gstatic.com
>   cdn.optimizely.com www.staticv.me".

I'm trying to add meta tag in layout

> checkout_index_index.xml

but the same error appears, also i am trying uploading in **SSL** server but is the same.

[image]

This is the error outputed in checkout
[image]

Anyone have any idea to integrate **Visa-checkout** in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the CSP Module.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html

To completely disable CSP you can use

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_Csp
```